# Can't Install pip2

Tags: python, pip

I accidentally uninstalled pip2 and can't successfully reinstall it.

I tried reinstalling it using `apt-get install python-pip`, however if I try to run the `pip` command, it defaults to anaconda's pip, and if I try to run the `pip2` command, I get the following error:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/pip2: No such file or directory`

The computer is Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.

Comment: why do you need another pip if you have pip with anaconda installed?

Comment: Refer this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/780502/ubuntu-16-pip-install-installs-to-python-3-instead-of-2

Comment: anaconda's pip defaults to adding packages to anaconda's python3. For work, I need to run programs written in python2, hence I need to use pip2 to install them

Comment: Did you try to use full path? /usr/bin/pip

Answer (score 0):

## Installing with get-pip.py

To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Then run the following:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Referance: [Installation pip 19.0.1 documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: This does not work as get-pip.py has ended support for python2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must have uninstalled `pip` from your system Python, because you mention that typing `pip` in bash defaults to Anaconda's `pip`. This is because by default Anaconda adds some lines to your `.bashrc` that look like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
# [some stuff]
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Specifically, those lines add the Anaconda directory to the beginning of your path so that commands you type default to the Anaconda versions. If you comment those lines out in your `.bashrc` and then restart your terminal, `pip` and `python` should refer to your default installations. You can check this by running the following:

```
# before commenting stuff out in .bashrc
$ which python
/home/username/.anaconda3/bin/python
$ which pip2
/home/username/.anaconda3/bin/pip2

# after commenting stuff out in .bashrc and restarting
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which pip2
/usr/bin/pip2
```